# How to make two buttons inline if each of them is in different form?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How can I make the submit buttons in two different forms inline ? The first form must be a block level element but the second one can be inline-block.

```
<form action="#">
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Enter title">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="body">Body</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="body" id="body" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>

</form>

<form action="#">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">DELETE</button>
</form>
```

Comment: With so little info, float is plenty enough : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zQayoj

Comment: It will be easier for people to help if you attach you CSS code also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Float is a very good choice to use...But we can also use 
the display: inline;  Property for form element...Like this..

Suggestion : -

```
   form{
       display: inline;
     }
```

This is also the best option... And display inline carries 
the gap between the elements...So delete and update 
buttons will looking good.

Answer (score 0):

Simply move the `delete` button into the other form tag. This should work.

```html
<form action="#">
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Enter title">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="body">Body</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="body" id="body" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>

    <form action="#">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">DELETE</button>
    </form>

</form>
```